# ClassCastException when I do ObjectList = StringList

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist

I created list using method `Arrays.asList()` with one String.
Then I assigned it to `List<Object>`, and I get ClassCastException.
What did I do wrong?

The code is:

```
class A {
    Object value;

    public <T> T getAValue() {
        return (T) value;
    }
}
```

And then I do

```
A a = new A();
a.value = "abc";

List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(a.getAValue());
```

Comment: Could you show your code?  The answer is, "A `List<String>` isn't a `List<Object>`," but a more complete solution would also include a way to help you get around what you're facing.

Comment: To expand on what Makato said, not all Objects are Strings, so you get a ClassCastException

Comment: @wero:  If it's a manual cast then you wouldn't; Java assumes you know what you're doing.

Comment: @cricket_007:  I think the case that they're trying to do is `(List<Object>) someListTypeStringInstance`, not the other way around.

Comment: It's not at all clear how you are getting a `ClassCastException`. You will never get a `ClassCastException` when casting a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>` because at runtime there's no difference. We need to see your code!

Comment: I think you need to add `A<T>` and `T value` instead of `Object value`, then `public T getAValue()` and just `return value`, then to instantiate `A<String> a = new A<String>()`

Comment: @cricket_007 can I solve this without editing `A`?

Comment: No, you *have* to edit `A` to fix this.  There is absolutely ***no*** guarantee that `value` is the type you're trying to cast to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** cannot add type info on `A` (i.e. use `class A<T>`), then a simple cast solves your issue, like this ([demo](https://ideone.com/Dvl8e8)):

```
A a = new A();
a.value = "abc";
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList((Object) a.getAValue());
```

This is safe, because everything is an `Object`, but the clean way is to use type info on `A`, *as stated in another answer* ([demo](https://ideone.com/n3Eror)):

```
A<String> a = new A<String>();
a.value = "abc";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a.getAValue());
```

Also note that you should use a setter for `value` (i.e. no `a.value = "..."`).

---

Some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    class A<T>{
        T value;

        public T getAValue(){
            return value;
        }

        public static void main(String... args){
            A a = new A();
            a.value = "abc";

            List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(a.getAValue());
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println(a.value.getClass());
        }
    }
```

Note the simplified syntax by declaring the generic type 'T' when declaring `class A<T>` T's type is bound to String and it is unnecessary to cast the return value in the getAValue(), generics take care of that for you.

Comment: Why do you use raw type for A in main? Also note that the OP said in a comment A cannot be modified.